# Как сделать transition delay для Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Есть много элементов на странице, которые используют один и тот же transition, например:

```
<template>
  <transition name="fadeInOut">
    <div class="class1"></div> // должен появится с задержкой 1s
  </transition>
  <transition name="fadeInOut">
    <div class="class2"></div> // должен появится с задержкой 2s
  </transition>
  <transition name="fadeInOut">
    <div class="class3"></div> // должен появится с задержкой 3s
  </transition>
</template>
```

Подскажите, как правильно реализовать данную анимацию, чтобы не пришлось создавать несколько разных блоков с v-enter-to и т.д.

Спасибо всем кто ответит!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template>
<transition
  v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter"
  v-on:enter="enter"
  v-on:leave="leave"
>
  <slot/>
</transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    duration: Number,
  },
  data: () => ({
    show: false
  }),
  methods: {
    beforeEnter: function (el) {
      el.style.opacity = 0
    },
    enter: function (el, done) {
      Velocity(el, { opacity: 1 }, { duration: this.duration, complete: done });
    },
    leave: function (el, done) {
      Velocity(el, { opacity: 0 }, { complete: done, duration: this.duration })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Вот тебе готовый компонент

Comment: Не важно какой контент будет внутри

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Сделай отдельным компонентом и через js изменяй скорость анимации `<fade-in-out :delay="300">...`

Comment: Привет. Т.е. если у меня на странице есть 15 таких элементов, мне 15 компонентов делать?

Comment: Нет один в котором меняешь пропсы и всё

Comment: А то что внутри каждого дива будет разный совершенно контент ничего?